# How to add Data from multiple rows of CSV in one single HTTP request in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I've a situation, I want to use CSV data row wise in respective manner in single request, So how do I call the data from CSV and use in form of ${Data} where I want to input. Eg. If want to use data of 2nd row how do I fetch that and use with function ${secondRowdataColumn1} and at some other value be like ${secondRowdataColumn3}, similarly in same body if I need to add data from 3rd row column 5 i.e. something like ${ThirdRowdataColumn5}
Any Idea how it can be done ?

Couldn't find any solution

Answer (score -1):

See [__CSVRead() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead):

- `${__CSVRead(test.csv,0)}` - read 1st column from the `test.csv` file
- `${__CSVRead(test.csv,1)}` - read 2nd column from the `test.csv` file
- `${__CSVRead(test.csv,next)}` - proceed to the next row

It's also possible to use [__groovy() function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) if you want to travel "back", like

- `${__groovy(new File('test.csv').readLines().get(0),)}` - read 1st line from the `test.csv` file
- `${__groovy(new File('test.csv').readLines().get(1),)}` - read 2nd line from the `test.csv` file
- you can also call `split()` function to "break" values by separator, i.e.

`new File('test.csv').readLines().get(0).split(',')[0]` - row 1 column 1